# Load elements in as Map is populated - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, map-function

I have a React component as so:

```
import {LoadingSVG} from "../util/svgs"
import {Investor} from "../util/cards"

export default function SearchList(props) {
  const [investors, setInvestors] = useState(new Map());
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
      props.filtered.map(async (investor) => {
        fetch(`example.com/api/${investor}`).then(r => r.json()).then((data) => {
          // Process data
          setInvestors((p) => new Map(p.set(investor, data)))
        }) 
      })
    ]).then(() => setLoaded(true))
  })

  if(!loaded) return <span><LoadingSVG/> Loading...</span>
  return (
    <>
      {Array.from(investors).map([,data]) => {return (<Investor data={data}/>)}}
    </>
  )
}
```

It is meant to be a list of investors in a certain unnamed product. However, to get the information of each investor, a fetch request must be made to an API, which takes time. However, since there are a large amount of investors, and thus a large amount of fetch requests it takes a long time before the entire thing loads.

How can I make it so each `Investor` element loads as it finishes fetching?

Comment: move the fetch and loading to `Investor` component

Comment: why are you using a map for investors?

Comment: @RameshReddy It worked! I moved loading the `Investor`, and now each investor loads independently